# mapping an array onto the UI is not displaying elements right

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Some background for the problem: I have a dynamic input field form in which the user can select the social media platform that they are a part of by choosing an option from a drop-down menu. There is also a corresponding text input in which the user can input their username of that social media platform. The user can add input fields or delete input fields as well that follows the same format. The form looks like this on the UI in the following screenshot:

[social_media_form_before_deleted_input_field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocCrN.png)

And here's the revelant JSX code for it:

```
{socialMediaInputs.map((input, index) =>
                <>
                    <tr className="socialMediaOptionsRow">
                        <td>
                            {index === 0 ? null :
                                <button onClick={event => handleDelete(event, input.id)}>Delete</button>
                            }
                        </td>
                        <td >
                            <select
                                id="socialMediaOptions"
                                onChange={event => handleSocialMediaOptions(event, setIsTextInputDisabled)}
                                required
                                name={input.id}
                            >
                                <option>choose</option>
                                <option name="socialMedia" value={"Twitter"}>Twitter</option>
                                <option name="socialMedia" value={"Facebook"}>Facebook</option>
                                <option name="socialMedia" value={"LinkedIn"}>LinkedIn</option>
                                <option name="socialMedia" value={"Instagram"}>Instagram</option>
                                <option name="socialMedia" value={"Medium"}>Medium</option>
                                <option name="socialMedia" value={"Other"}>Other</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <input
                                type="text"
                                onChange={handleAccountNameInput}
                                name={input.id}
                                disabled={isTextInputDisabled}
                                required
                            />
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                       <button 
                          onClick={handleAddBtnClick} 
                          disabled={socialMediaInputs.length >= 5}
                       >
                         <CgMathPlus/>       
                         Add
                       </button>
                    </tr>
                </>
```

The problem is whenever I delete an input field by pressing the delete button, the input field does get deleted from `socialMediaInputs`--a state value in which all of the values of the inputs fields are stored and gets mapped onto the UI, as seen in the screenshot and the code--but it still appears on the UI. So, based upon the screen shot above, if I press the delete button for the select option input field that has `LinkedIn`, what gets deleted on the UI is not that input field, but always the last input field--in this case, the option input field with `Instagram` selected. Here's a screenshot of that result:

[social_media_form_after_deleted_input_field](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xh6V.png)

As you can see in the second screen shot, the object that contains `company: LinkedIn` does get deleted from `socialMediaInputs`, but it still appears on the UI. How can I get a input field to be deleted from the UI when the user clicks on its corresponding 'Delete' button?

And here's the javacript code that handles the delete button being pressed:

```
const handleDelete = (event, id_) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const inputs_ = socialMediaInputs.filter(input => input.id !== id_);
        setSocialMediaInputs(inputs_);
    }
```

EDIT:

When I add a key to each tr, the specific tr does get deleted when the delete button gets pressed, but any row below the row that was deleted gets reset on the UI. So, if I delete the row with `Facebook`  selected, in the first screenshot below, it does get deleted. But the rows below it gets reset--which is something that I don't want--which is seen in the second screenshot below.

[form_with_key_before_deletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyHdd.png)

[form_with_key_after_deletion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dZz64.png)

Comment: From `setSocialMediaInputs(inputs_);` `setSocialMediaInputs` looks like to be a function but here `socialMediaInputs.map` you are iterating an array

Comment: can you use the debugger and figure out what is the value of `inputs_`? This should probably give you enough context to figure out the problem yourself  Also you have used `==` instead of `===` is that the problem? Another workaround would be not used your id's to begin with ( only do this if you are not going to move the drop downs around ) and just use the array indices and `array.splice( index, 1)` to remove the element at the desired position.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you forgot `key` attribute on mapping an array and rendering the same in UI. Without the `key`, shadow dom would be confused to understand the item inside the array got changed.

Comment: k, thanks. So what do I put in as the value for the key attribute? the id of each object in the array in ```setMediaInputs```?

Comment: Id can be used if it is unique, or something else unique

Comment: Has it fixed the issue? @GabeT

Comment: Kinda. I place the key attribute with the id as its value in each table row (tr), but when I click the delete button, the specific row does get deleted from the UI, but all of the rows below it gets reset back to their default value if the user puts any input in them.

Comment: I added some more screenshots above

Comment: Ooh, is this question still open? Do you require any assistance at this point of time?